# How web server remembers the web browser with ssl connection

Tags: ssl

When a SSL connection is built btw the server and a web browser, does the server records the browser? (i.e., if the user changes to another browser, or a machine, or a wireless network, the server could know the change?)

Answer (score 0):

SSL doesn't matter in your question (the only exception is when client-side authentication is used and the server authenticates the user by certificate and not by any remote info).

In general, the answer depends on how exactly the server organizes "sessions", i.e. how the client is identified between requests. Usually this is implemented using cookies. And cookies can contain (or not contain) client's IP address and other information that is available to the server from request. So if the user can transfer a cookie from one browser to another, then the session can be continued. If the cookie is not IP-bound, it can be transferred (or stolen, btw) to another computer and used there.